# In TypeScript, defining a function that maps a set of functions

Tags: typescript, mobx, typescript-generics

I'm trying to define a function that will take a set of functions and wrap them in MobX's `flow`. My actual code does a bit more than just wrap with `flow`, but that isn't important to this question. I've devised some TypeScript types that will successfully do the mapping, but am having trouble getting the function to match the types.

First I thought I could use use lodash's `mapValues` like this:

```
const actions = {
    a: function* (a: number) { return "test" },
    b: function* (b: string) { return 1 }
};

const flowed = mapValues(actions, f => flow(f));
```

But `mapValues` typing assumes that every property has the same type, so this generates an error:

```
(parameter) f: ((a: number) => Generator<never, string, unknown>) | ((b: string) => Generator<never, number, unknown>)
Argument of type '((a: number) => Generator<never, string, unknown>) | ((b: string) => Generator<never, number, unknown>)' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: number) => Generator<any, string, any> | AsyncGenerator<any, string, any>'.
  Type '(b: string) => Generator<never, number, unknown>' is not assignable to type '(a: number) => Generator<any, string, any> | AsyncGenerator<any, string, any>'.
    Types of parameters 'b' and 'a' are incompatible.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

Doing some research and experimenting, I came up with the following generic types to do the conversion:

```
type Flowing<T> = T extends (...args: infer A) => Generator<any, infer R, any> ? (...args: A) => Promise<R> : never;

type Flowify<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: Flowing<T[P]>;
}

declare function flowify<T>(o: T): Flowify<T>;

const flowed = flowify(actions);
```

Now `flowed` has the correct type:

```
{
    a: (a: number) => Promise<string>;
    b: (b: string) => Promise<number>;
}
```

The problem is that I haven't figured out how to create the `flowify` function so that it matches the types without casting. Here is what I have so far, but I'd like to avoid having to use `as`:

```
function flowify<T extends object>(o: T): Flowify<T> {
    return mapValues(o, f => flow(f as any)) as Flowify<T>;
}
```

I've already worked on this task for a few hours and hope to get some expert eyes on the problem. I've got this code in a [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2ASWBATgQ2AeywB4AVeJVAGihICUIBnAVwBtgA+KAXigAoA3HCyYQAXDXIpgAbQDWEEPgBmExFIC61eSHENgWAJYA7AObVk+FiykH8R8WTWoAlN051GrYAG4AsAChQSCgAWRwwADUhEQZuKFIoCAAPTCMAE1j8J2BqD2Y2dl4shAdzIRY4HGRZcUlUDGw8QlJc+nyOVy5OAG8oaQAFKGMobWUadQc2rygAXz9-AIsjPSgAW3Co4UZxMMjoxjiixGoDTFxMCE6egKhbqCWVrE82OO6ZqBxYnCMQeZu7urAAB02gYRwQziBSkIAFEqgALXi8bRXKDdf53O5PdpyBTqOKnRoXcG4kAfWKjFRBCBjYqaEYKajFZzzTEzFkBDFQJ7AJhYIzc54+AIzTmBcDQABiLHwAHc4kRaNQAIJYEyxZKpDIfH7SdSFEwQIxEwjiXhAi04NUMcSq9WogDiRpNxG+IGoSp1IHYqPNluttutqP6WHwqwMDAgivY8zSKBYVugD2AUCUMtl4mlcr+-mTH1QtmWry5OHESiYRgLdgAVHxS1AjExVnBsK5ejy+QKAESYPRd2aULlwMsVqtGWu8YdQPSGUxtwW8-lQACMsxFObzablEDSq546z2WzBVWAhYY1BUXVT6d4SmcHIW4uCWdlxhMpE4PBIiRSRu1fqBK11XEYwlGwKBlUdZ1zmaN0TiMMCsCgT03U4AB+PgLUAgMIODUNw0jaMoHEY1+GwHNqSgF8DCUEAP2LfxMQGIYBUpcZM3TN9SAGfV5lFR9y0rU87GvOUaLo79NT-TJskKfAHGcDixNo+j0UYrEIEXAUD02GIigvNxRNlW9yS9e9TOolSSBjEUxU3dMdwAJjiLdX1o3gTzPB8AkoiwsCeVASAlOJqTGVynPmIA).

Comment: I think the type assertion here is not that big a deal. Generic function implementation with conditional or mapped types tend to have type assertions.

Comment: Just because they often do doesn't mean they have to. Are you saying that it's not possible to write a function for this with correct typing?